# Laravel, property not found

Tags: laravel, properties

Trying to get property from a object in laravel. I have this:

```html
public function index()
    {
        $firmen = Companies::all();
        $allcountcompanies = Companies::count();
        $agent = Agent::find($firmen->agent_firma_id);

        return view('companies',compact(['firmen'],['allcountcompanies'],['agent']));
    }
```

The Exeption gives me that:

```
Property [agent_firma_id] does not exist on this collection instance.
```

But when i put the id eg 1001 it shows corrent entry in db field.
What i0'm doing wrong?

Info:
CompaniesController.php (table: br_firma)
AgentController.php (table: br_firma_agents)

Table "br_firma_agents" contains a foreign_key from table "br_firma".

Comment: `$firmen` is a collcetion you cannot use `$firmen->agent_firma_id` you need to loop over to get single one

Comment: you should create relationship then do `$firmen = Companies::with('agent')->get();` https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 0):

You are getting id from collection.

```php
$firmens = Companies::all();
```

it return collection you may be use it useing loop and get one by one data as

```php
for($firmens as $firmen){
  $agent = Agent::find($firmen->agent_firma_id);
}
```

---

Or you create relation between Company and agent as,
In company model define relation as

```php
public function agents(){
    return $this->hasMany(Agent::class);
}
```

and in agent model define relation as

```php
public function company(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Companies::class);
}
```

and then call it as in controller,

```php
$data = Companies::with('agents')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access an **agent_firma_id** from a collection of companies, you could first use a loop on that collection,or use an index on that collection,
you could try

```
$firmens = Companies::all();
foreach($firmens as $firmen){
   $agent = Agent::find($firmen->agent_firma_id);
}
```